# How can i get multiple value using dropdown select option data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get two data using data attribute and display the two value in two separate input field readonly.

I can get one value properly. data-price, but I can't get data-saleP.

```js
$('.selectProduct').on('change', function() {
  $('.regularPrice')
    .val(
      $(this).find(':selected').data('price')
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectProduct" class="form-control selectProduct" name="productId">
   <option selected="">Select Product</option>
   <option data-price="150" data-salep="50" value="1">Product 1</option>
   <option data-price="120" data-salep="110" value="2">Product 2</option>                                                                                </select>
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label>Regular Price</label>
            <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control regularPrice" id="regularPrice" name="regularPrice" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label>Sale Price</label>
            <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control salePrice" id="salePrice" name="salePrice" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And cant you not just do `$('.salePrice').val($(this).find(":selected").data("salep"))` like you did with the other

Comment: *but I can't get data-saleP* - note that `.data(name)` is **case sensitive** so if you did what you said in your question and tried `.data("saleP")` it would not work.  Always use all lowercase for `data-salep` and `.data("salep")`.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes now working well. Thank you

Comment: @freedomn-m yes i can understand thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, use same code with `salep` like:

```js
$('.selectProduct').on('change', function() {
  $('.regularPrice')
    .val(
      $(this).find(':selected').data('price')
    );
    $('.salePrice')
    .val(
      $(this).find(':selected').data('salep')
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectProduct" class="form-control selectProduct" name="productId">
  <option selected="">Select Product</option>
  <option data-price="150" data-salep="50" value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option data-price="120" data-salep="110" value="2">Product 2</option>
</select>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <label>Regular Price</label>
      <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control regularPrice" id="regularPrice" name="regularPrice" value="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <label>Sale Price</label>
      <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control salePrice" id="salePrice" name="salePrice" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. I try this way but i am failour. Now working well.

Comment: Can you acept my question?

Comment: Yes. i can apply your code in my project. now working.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i already voted this post. but my vote can't display because i am new here. They can tell me first complete 15 answer then your vote counted. 

Answer accept, I didn't know about this feature. So now i know. And i can accept your answer. Please see

Comment: Don't worry :) see next time